# How to read and write Parquet files to/from GCS using the Arrow/Parquet C++ libraries?

Tags: c++, parquet, apache-arrow

I have a need to access Parquet formatted data on GCS.  We are using the C++ libraries that are available for both Apache Arrow and Parquet.  Reading/writing to local disk is relatively straightforward using the Parquet C++ library.  However if one wants to do the same, but with GCS, the effort appears to be complicated.  I've done some research into it.  I've noticed that there is a GCS filesystem class available in Arrow, as well as a Parquet adapter.  Unfortunately the GCS filesystem code isn't included in the version of the library that we have installed (4.0.0).  Don't know if that was by option during the unpacking and installation process or if it wasn't available then.  Either way, some admin work will be necessary if we are to develop this capability on our boxes.  That is do-able obviously.  That aside, I wanted to pose the question to see if anyone has been down this road before and could offer an approach.  Or a suggested approach.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GCS is supported in Arrow since 7.0.0 (see release notes here: https://arrow.apache.org/release/). I suppose a good starting points would be docs: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/filesystem.html#google-cloud-storage-filesystem or examples from tests: https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/cpp/src/arrow/filesystem/gcsfs_test.cc

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I read the documentation you referred to; I was hoping to see some actual working code written by someone who had done it.  That said, I am working on that now and will answer my own question when I get something up and working.  Thanks again!

Comment: GCS support is pretty new so hence the lack of examples. Opening a cookbook issue would help in that direction :).
https://github.com/apache/arrow-cookbook/issues

Another option is to use the Python API and look at this example:
https://arrow.apache.org/cookbook/py/io.html#reading-partitioned-data-from-s3

Comment: Ok thanks.  I am experimenting with it now and will post back with results.

Comment: The issue for me is that I need to read/write Parquet data from/to a GCS server.  A scan of the new classes doesn't indicate that this is possible, at least not directly.  I'll continue to dig to see if I can turn anything up.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, through experimentation I was able to read a Parquet file that I stored in my service account on a GCS server.  The first item to note is that I downloaded and built the latest version of the Arrow/Parquet libraries (version 8.0.0 as of the date of this posting).  The GCS functionality is indeed new as of version 7.0.0.  Note further that the build of this version of the library requires you to enable the GCS functionality explicitly, as it doesn't come with the "default build" if you will.  Finally, Arrow GCS has a few dependencies that you'll need to be aware of, namely libcurl and openssl.  I built the latest-n-greatest of those too in order to make this work.  And you'll need the GCS SDK.  Since we already use the GCS C++ library, that was merely a matter of pointing to our existing GCP library.  If you don't have the GCP C++ library, you will need to download and build that as well.

All preliminaries accounted for, here is the code (exception handling removed for clarity reasons, etc.):

```
constexpr char jsonKey[] = R"""( [snipped for brevity reasons] )""";

const arrow::fs::GcsOptions gcsOptions = arrow::fs::GcsOptions::FromServiceAccountCredentials( jsonKey );

static std::shared_ptr<arrow::fs::GcsFileSystem> myGCSFileSystem = arrow::fs::GcsFileSystem::Make( gcsOptions );

const std::string path( "my_bucket/my_parquet_file.parquet" );
arrow::Result<std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::RandomAccessFile>> openResult = myGCSFileSystem->OpenInputFile( path );
std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::RandomAccessFile> arrowFile;
if( true == openResult.ok() )
{
   arrowFile = openResult.ValueOrDie();

}
else
{
   throw std::runtime_error( "Unable to open input file on GCS server" + openResult.status().ToString() );

}

// Create a ParquetFileReader instance
std::unique_ptr<parquet::ParquetFileReader> parquet_reader = parquet::ParquetFileReader::Open( arrowFile );
```

From there the process of reading metadata/data from a Parquet file on a GCS server is identical to reading it on a local disk.  I will therefore dispense with its inclusion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I couldn't get this working with the 8.0.0 release directly, as `ARROW_GCS` was not defined in `arrow/util/config.h` and therefore the GCS file system never got enabled. This was fixed in https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/12763, but as far as I can tell isn't part of a release yet. Building directly from the `master` branch worked for me.

Comment: When I built the Arrow/Parquet libraries, I added the -DARROW_GCS definition to the CMake script.  That resulted in a domino effect of various library dependencies being added to the result.  However it did work.  We are utilizing this functionality at present.